# Davening together with the shliach tzibbur on Rosh HaShanah

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, tzibur-community, chazzan-prayer-leader, rosh-hashanah-new-year

On Rosh HaShanah one was not able to daven the quiet Shemoneh Esrei with the tzibbur. Now he wants to daven together with the Shliach Tzibbur (in order that it should be considered "tefillah b'tzibbur") and will daven word-for-word with the shliach tzibbur may he also say yotzros?

Comment: You could just listen and say Amen to the Brachot.

Comment: Yehoshua, is there a specific reason you asked about _RH_ specifically and not more generally about any time _yotz'ros_ (technically _k'rovos_, _musafos_, or _k'rovetz_) are said?

Comment: @msh210 I probably asked about Rosh HaShanah because this was asked close to to Tishrei and was the example I had in mind. It's however "lav davka".

Comment: As I understand it, if when the tzibbur reaches Kedusha, you won't be mid-amida, but will be free to say kedusha with them, you can start late and still have davened with the tzibbur.  Since a lot of piyutim are before kedusha, as a practical matter, one could be fairly late & still say his silent amida before the shatz reaches kedusha.  To be davening with the shatz, you need to start when he starts.  You could probably finish before he hits kedusha. (Somewhat tongue-in-cheek)